# How to pause and resume Quartz scheduler in Spring integration test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing, quartz-scheduler

I'm testing Quartz application with `@SpringBootTest`. I need to initialize the database with test data before scheduler runs any job. Is it possible to pause and resume the Quartz scheduler in Spring integration test?

Comment: Just a quick idea: implement the initialization as a separate job and start it prior to the application in test. This way you will not change anything in the tested application.

Comment: there's [standby()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.3.2/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#standby()) method which should halt the scheduler. Or eventually you can try to call `clear()` and then `start()` depends on what works for your usecase.